# Integer attribute in core data show up differently

Tags: ios, core-data

In my core data entity, there is an attribute of Integer 32 type named validity.

There are two objects created earlier using this method:

```
- (void) AddMandatoryItems
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newMonitorItem = [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MonitorItem"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //
    // Other codes here
    //
    [newMonitorItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:35]
                      forKey:@"validity"];
   [self.monitorItemArray addObject:newMonitorItem];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    //
    // other codes here
    //
    [newMonitorItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:90]
                      forKey:@"validity"];
    [self.monitorItemArray addObject:newMonitorItem];

    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.

}
```

The validity values are 35 and 90 for the first and second objects respectively.

The two values are loaded like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

//
// Other codes here
//

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MonitorItem"];
    self.monitorItemArray = [[managedObjectContext
                              executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                              error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"viewDidLoad.monitorItemArray[1].validity: %d", (int)[self.monitorItemArray[1] valueForKey:@"validity"]);

}
```

the result from the NSLog is shown below:

**2014-05-14 14:55:15.939 SGRecencyMonitor[3086:70b] viewDidLoad.monitorItemArray[1].validity: 1442**

As shown the value should be 90 instead of 1442. However a check on the cellForRowAtIndexPath method below returns correct result:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSManagedObject *monitorItem = [self.monitorItemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//
// code to display each row here
//
    NSLog(@"ItemViewController tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath Validity: %@", [monitorItem valueForKey:@"validity"]);

    return cell;
}
```

the result is as follow:

**2014-05-14 14:55:15.948 SGRecencyMonitor[3086:70b] ItemViewController tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath Validity: 90**

Can someone please explain to me why I cannot get the correct result using [self.monitorItemArray[1] valueForKey:@"validity"] I am using this method to pass the object self.monitorItemArray to another view. I can't retrieve the correct values through it. Below is the segue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"UpdateView"])
    {
        NSManagedObject *selectedItem = [self.monitorItemArray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        ItemUpdateViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.ItemReceived = selectedItem;
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong? Thank you

Comment: If you want `int` it should be `[(NSNumber *)[self.monitorItemArray[1] valueForKey:@"validity"] intValue]`. In your check it should be `[(NSNumber *)[self.monitorItemArray[1] valueForKey:@"validity"] stringValue]` but it seems that for some reason NSNumber casts to NSString implicitly

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance you're using `%d` as a format specifier - this expects an integer, but you pass it an `NSNumber`, which is an object. You're seeing the integer of the object's memory address. In the second instance you're using `%@`, which expects an object, and you're seeing the result of the `NSNumber`'s `description` method, which just prints out the number value.

Either change the first format specifier to `%@` or pass in the `integerValue` from the number object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MonitorItem"];
self.monitorItemArray = [[managedObjectContext
                          executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                          error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSNumber *n = [self.monitorItemArray[1]     valueForKey:@"validity"];
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad.monitorItemArray[1].validity: %d", [n intValue]);
}

// it works for me
```

Comment: @BusDriver: If one of the provided answers helped you solve you problem, then you should accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yes. kaman has pointed out my error in understanding. jrturton shows me the error in the format. nmh demonstrated to me the how to and I have also adopted it in my coding. Thank you guys. Please pardon my ignorance.